# How to get services post data(json format) callback function?

Tags: 7, services

I am using services module and rest API its working fine.

But i need to create a `menu callback` where i get the `json post` data and save in database.

How to get the `json` data in menu callback?

Comment: Do you mean the POST data? It's in `$_POST`

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: You need to create a custom service resource, which in turn creates the necessary menu callback and will allow you to POST data to it. Here's an example: http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Services/Create_a_Custom_Service/Custom_Service_Resource_with_Arguments

Comment: Thanks @tyler.frankenstein for sharing the docs. I will check it and let you know. Actually i need to alter user registration response result(uid,uri). i need more field value instated of(uid and uri). Thats why i want to go for custom service. If i can alter the registration response. It will good for me. If there is any docs for alter the user registration response. Please share.

Comment: I've answered the question to your follow up comment below, I'd recommend updating your question to match.

Answer (score 0):

> Through comments, we determined the OP would like to alter the results
>   of the user registration service resource...

To alter the results of user registration data, implement [hook_services_request_postprocess_alter()](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/services/tree/docs/services.alter.api.php?h=7.x-3.x) in your [custom module](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7), for example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_services_request_postprocess_alter().
 */
function my_module_services_request_postprocess_alter($controller, $args, &$result) {
  if ($controller['callback'] == '_user_resource_register') {
    $result->foo = 'bar';
  }
}
```

This will allow the value of `foo` to be available to your application that is calling the user registration service resource.